# Exporting comments only from one drupal site to another

Tags: migrations, comments, importing-exporting, backups

How can i export only comments from a Drupal Site (Live) to a Drupal site (Dev).

The content of both sites is same. The live site only has new users and comments. I already exported the users and imported into Dev Site.

I looked into many modules but non on them only allow comments to be exported. Can i simply copy some MySql tables ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Drupal 7.

Use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module and create a table view of node comments.

Add fields: Node ID (nid), Comment ID (cid), Comment Title, Comment Body, Commment Author, Created Date.

For export, use [Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) and export the CSV file.

For import, use the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module + [Feeds Comment Processor](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_comment_processor) and import your CSV.

Checkout this [Feeds Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXgjFRn7ty4) (this is for nodes, not comments, but it will give you an idea on how feeds with the CSV import works).

--

Exporting MySQL tables approach:

Never done it like this, but if I were you, I would look for all the tables that have the name comment, export those and import.

Note sure if it will work as simply as that, but worth a try.

Comment: perfect, works like a charm. (y)

Comment: @brainHax just wondering, which method did you use?

Comment: the first one. Views , feeds and data export.

Comment: What about Drupal 8?

Comment: @Progonat you'll need to use the [Migrate API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api). I highly suggest you watch youtube videos about it, it can be hard to grasp from just reading the docs.